# Dundas Dashboard Entering longitude and latitude on maps

Tags: latitude-longitude, dundas

How can I insert longitude and latitude coordinates to a map on Dundas Dashboard? I have a table in SQL with `City`, `Province`, `Longitude`, and `latitude` columns, but when I enter the dataset into the map, it doesn't give me the option to use the tables for x: longitude and y: latitude. The selections for these are greyed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I have figured out how to do this. When you drag your map into the sheet and dropped the data set onto the map and followed the steps. You then click on the map so it opens the properties bar on the right hand side. There you can select **symbols**. Create new symbol and give it a proper name. Just underneath the **tooltip** in the **Symbols tab** is the **X(longitude) and Y(latitude)** there you can insert the values that is needed to pinpoint the city on the map. Also if you wish to have the **name displayed** on the map of the city you have entered the location. Click on the map so it is selected. then on the properties menu on the right hand side look for a drop down marked **LABELS**. Expand the labels and set **ENABLE SYMBOL LABELING** to **true**. All the names of the cities will now display on the map.

When you are finished this is what your map should Look like

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I checked with our support team on this questions as well. Manually adding the symbols isn't always the most efficient way of adding them, ideally you should auto generate the symbols during data binding, please see this article for more information goo.gl/OzFau.

You mentioned the longitude/latitude selections are greyed out, this happens when the columns aren't recognized as numeric. Please check the column's data type and let us know if that is the case.

Comment: I have checked on the Numeric columns. The two columns for long\lat is on numeric, but it still giving the same problem. I'm not too worried at this stage about it as the settings that i manually put into the map has worked for me now. But at least this will help someone in the future if they get the same problem.